# AWS Customizing single ELB to serve 2 kind of services

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

My Application serves 2 kind of services, stateful and stateless. Stateful services will be served by dedicated micro instance per user, whereas stateless services served by common server. Authentication will be done only once (mostly done by the stateless server)

How to I configure both of the servers under single Amazon Elastic Load Balancer(ELB). So that some of the requests needs to  be routed to stateless server and some of the requests to be routed to the dedicated micro instance.

I cannot run all the services in my stateful server(micro instance) because its not needed for all the time. The micro instance needs be allocated to the user only based on the particular request. I used AutoScaling to scale up/down the micro instance. And I used session stickiness in my ELB so that all the requests will be routed to same micro instance.

I'm using python tornado webserver. Suggest me a way to configure my ELB.

Thanks
Adhi

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with just one ELB, you'd need to use at least two for this scenario.

Comment: If I do so both the service will ask for authentication since the domain is different. Is it? or Is there a way to crack that? I'm storing the authentication information in Cookie.

Comment: That depends on your authentication/request routing approach, provided information isn't enough to answer this question.

Comment: I'm using Google-openid authentication & python routes for url routing. And I'm storing authentication information in cookie.